# Setting boot disk size for autoscaling kubernetes cluster through Terraform

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to add the boot disk size to the node auto-provisioned Kubernetes cluster as follows:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "gc-dev-kube-ds0" {
        .
        .
        .

      cluster_autoscaling {
    enabled = true

    resource_limits {
      resource_type = "cpu"
      minimum       = 4
      maximum       = 150
    }

    resource_limits {
      resource_type = "memory"
      minimum       = 4
      maximum       = 600
    }

    resource_limits {
      resource_type = "nvidia-tesla-v100"
      minimum       = 0
      maximum       = 4
    }

  }

  disk_size_gb = 200
}
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on kubernetes.tf line 65, in resource "google_container_cluster" "gc-dev-kube-ds0":
  65:   disk_size_gb = 200

An argument named "disk_size_gb" is not expected here.
```

Also checked the terraform [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#cluster_autoscaling) but nothing is mentioned on this.

Answer (score 1):

The error is getting because the [disk_size_gb](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#disk_size_gb) module must be in the node_config block, as the following.

```
node_config {
      disk_size_gb = 200
}
```

The TerraForm documentation about [google_container_cluster](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster) the module needs to be under the block.

[image]

Comment: I have tried the above config but didn't work as per terraform documentation this configuration manages the default node pool, which isn't recommended to be used with Terraform.  I am looking for a config to be applied for all the nodes created through autoscaling. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#node_config

Comment: I edited my answer to clarified.